# Vectorize a double summation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, vectorization

[image]

If I have some double summation like this, how do I completely vectorize it? (No loops)

A good starting point would be to get vector i and j. For example if n = 2:

```
i = 0:2
j = c(0,0,1,0,1,2)
```

Then how should we approach next?

Answer (score 7):

1. `i = 0` and `j = 0` contribute nothing, so the summation can start from 1, not 0;
2. `outer` can be used to evaluate `j * i * (i + 1)` for all `i = 1, 2, ..., n` and `j = 1, 2, ..., n`, giving an `n`-by-`n` square matrix;
3. the summation is over `j <= i`, only involving elements in the lower triangular part of this matrix.

```
n <- 2
i <- 1:n
j <- 1:n
x <- outer(i, j, function (i, j) j * i * (i + 1))
sum(x[lower.tri(x, diag = TRUE)])
#[1] 20
```

A less intuitive but more efficient way is to generate `(i, j)` index for all the lower triangular elements directly.

```
n <- 2
i <- sequence(n:1, 1:n)
j <- rep(1:n, n:1)
sum(j * i * (i + 1))
#[1] 20
```

Actually, after some simple math, I realize that this simplifies to a single summation:

```
n <- 2
i <- 1:n
0.5 * c(crossprod(i * (i + 1)))
#[1] 20
```

Comment: Love the last simplified summation, +1! I believe you can do it further `n * (n + 1) * (n + 2) * (3 * n^2 + 6 * n + 1) / 30` :P

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Holy... This is not at all transparent to me :( I can expand `i * i * (i + 1) * (i + 1)` into `i^4 + 2 * i^3 + i^2`. I know the summation for the latter two terms but not for the `i^4`. How did you get this explicit result. You genius! Oh hang on, [I think I find it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)

Comment: Yes, exactly, Wiki is a good teacher :)

Answer (score 1):

**1) row/col** Use `row` and `col` to get matrices `i` and `j` and then just write out the formula multiplying by the inequality shown to zero out the cells above the diagonal.

```
n <- 2
i <- row(diag(n+1)) - 1
j <- col(i) - 1
sum( (i+1) * i * j * (j <= i) )
## [1] 20
```

**2) row/call from 1** Since the zero row and column don't actually contribute to the sum we could alternately use:

```
n <- 2
i <- row(diag(n))
j <- col(i)
sum( (i+1) * i * j * (j <= i) )
# [1] 20
```

**3) explicit polynomial** Another approach which builds on the former approaches is that it is clear that the result is a polynomial in n.
We can deduce what this polynomial is by regressing the values against n up to sufficiently large n.  From the regression coefficients we see that the coefficients above ^5 are effectively zero so

```
f <- function(n, i = row(diag(n)), j = col(i)) sum( (i+1) * i * j * (j <= i) )
DF <- data.frame(v = sapply(1:10, f), n = 1:10)
lm(v ~ poly(n, 9), DF)  # note that coefs above n^5 are zero
```

so from the coefficients

```
coef(lm(v ~ poly(n, 5, raw = TRUE), DF))
```

write out the polynomial explicitly:

```
f2 <- function(n) n/15 + n^2/2 + n^3/1.2 + n^4/2 + n^5/10

# test
f2(2)
## [1] 20

# another test
f(20)
## [1] 406868

f2(20)
## [1] 406868
```

### Check

To double check this we can use list comprehensions to get a direct translation to code.

```
library(listcompr)

sum( gen.vector((i + 1) * i * j, j <= i, i = 0:n, j = 0:n) )
## [1] 20
```

Comment: With Methematica: `In[4]:= Expand[Sum[(i + 1)*Sum[j*i, {j, 1, i}], {i, 1, n}]]; Out[4]= n/15 + n^2/2 + (5 n^3)/6 + n^4/2 + n^5/10`